# Compare two different pyspark dataframes

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, compare

I am currently working with an API environment that requires the usage of pyspark.
In this way, I need to execute a daily comparison between two dataframes in order to determine with records are new, updated and deleted.

Here is an example of two dataframes:

```
today = spark.createDataFrame([
  [1, "Apple", 5000, "A"],
  [2, "Banana", 4000, "A"],
  [3, "Orange", 3000, "B"],
  [4, "Grape", 4500, "C"],
  [5, "Watermelon", 2000, "A"]
], ["item_id", "name", "cost", "classification"])

yesterday = spark.createDataFrame([
  [1, "Apple", 5000, "B"],
  [2, "Bananas", 4000, "A"],
  [3, "Tangerine", 3000, "B"],
  [4, "Grape", 4500, "C"]
], ["item_id", "name", "cost", "classification"])
```

I want to compare both dataframes and determine what is new and what is updated. For the new items, I get it quite easy:

```
today.join(yesterday, on="item_id", how="left_anti").show()

# +---------+------------+------+----------------+
# | item_id |    name    | cost | classification |
# +---------+------------+------+----------------+
# |    5    | Watermelon | 2000 |       A        |
# +---------+------------+------+----------------+
```

However for the items that got updated, I have no idea how to compare those results. I need to get all the rows that have different values for the remaining columns of the dataframe.
My expected result, in the case above is:

```
# +---------+------------+------+----------------+
# | item_id |    name    | cost | classification |
# +---------+------------+------+----------------+
# |    1    |    Apple   | 5000 |       A        |
# |    2    |   Banana   | 4000 |       A        |
# |    3    |   Orange   | 3000 |       B        |
# +---------+------------+------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.subtract()` method to get `today`'s rows that not present in `yesterday`, then left-semi join with `yesterday`

```
today.subtract(yesterday).join(yesterday, on="item_id", how="left_semi").show()

# +-------+------+----+--------------+
# |item_id|  name|cost|classification|
# +-------+------+----+--------------+
# |      1| Apple|5000|             A|
# |      3|Orange|3000|             B|
# |      2|Banana|4000|             A|
# +-------+------+----+--------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

```
joined = today.join(yesterday, [today.item_id== yesterday.item_id] , how = 'inner' )
```

Then apply the filter for which the classification are not matching

```
fitlered = joined.filter(joined.today_classification != joined.yesterday_classification)
```

`filtered` dataframe is your required

Comment: How do I make sure that it fetches all the rows where any of the columns don't match?